# C# EF with Table-per-type Inheritance error to insert element: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'test.dbo.Cluster'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance, insert

I have the sql server DB with a base AbstractTable and two derived tables Table A and Table B

AbstractTable

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |

TableA

| PropertyA |
| --- |

TableB

| PropertyB |
| --- |

With Entity Framework (7.0.5) fluent annotation I wrote the classes

AbstractTable.cs

```
public abstract class AbstractTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

TableA.cs

```
public partial class TableA : AbstractTable{[..]}
```

TableB.cs

```
public partial class TableB : AbstractTable{[..]}
```

And the relative configuration file  e.g.

AbstractTableConfiguration.cs

```
public partial class AbstractTableConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractTable>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AbstractTable> entity)
    {
    }
}
```

TableAConfiguration.cs

```
public partial class TableAConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableAConfiguration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableAConfiguration> entity)
    {
    }
}
```

TableBConfiguration.cs

```
public partial class TableBConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableABConfiguration>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableBConfiguration> entity)
    {

    }
}
```

if I try to insert a record in the table it is inserted successfully

```
context.TableB.Add(x)
```

If I rename the TableB in Cluster (in all its occurrences and int the DB) it fails with error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'test.dbo.Cluster'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

It works only to specify the table name in the configuration file e.g.

```
public partial class ClusterConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cluster>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cluster> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable(nameof(Cluster));
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: try `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }`

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping between the c# classes and the database. You cannot change a c# class without performing a migration which will update the database table to match the c# classes.